# MS Word IEEE bibliography bad formatting

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

I'm having problems with Word's IEEE bibliography generator. My bibliography looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of my Word bibliography]

As you can see, for some reason brackets around the numbers are split into multiple lines. I need them to be in single line like this `[14] .......`. Any reason this might be happening and any way to fix this?

Comment: Which Word version (answer by adding to tags)?

Comment: @Destroy666 its word 365, also updated tags

Comment: The IEEE style generates its bibliography as a 2-column table. It looks as if for some reason you have the Table property "Automatically resize to fit contents *unchecked* when it needs to be *checked*. (AFAICS the stylesheet assigns 100% width (i.e. between the page margins) to the table and 1% width to column 1). Changing that should fix it at least temporarily, perhaps someone else can chip with "how to fix it permanently" (without actually changing the IEEE stylesheet!)

Comment: @jonsson I checked that setting. As it turned out it was actually checked so no solution there

Comment: @PiotrekWcisło OK, nevertheless I think the problem has to do with table column widths. Have you tried selecting the table and adjusting them (again, a temporary fix - you would probably have to redo it every time you regenerate the bibliography).

Comment: Yes, Ive been trying to adjust column width. It does work but breaks other things about bibliography so I'm doing trial and error until I get the solution, just microsoft things I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution to my problem was **disabling** `Automatically resize to fit contents` setting and then manually changing `column 1` width to `1.0 cm` so it fits all my numbers.